# Android SSL connection and certificate exchange via ssl socket

Tags: java, android

I am connecting to the server via ssl socket.Need to connect to the server and start the handshake with the server for certificate. I have tried by using  below code:

```
`String hostname = "abc.com";
SSLSocketFactory factory = HttpsURLConnection
.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
System.out.println("Creating a SSL Socket For "+hostname+" on port "+port);
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(hostname, port);
socket.startHandshake();
System.out.println("Handshaking Complete");
Certificate[] serverCerts = socket.getSession().getPeerCertificates();
System.out.println("Retreived Server's Certificate Chain");
```

I am unable to connect to the server with this option. do we need any keystore for communication. Do i need to do the hostname verification before contacting the server, can any body comment on this.
 `

Comment: What is happening ? Please elaborate on "unable to connect".

Comment: When i tried to connect to the server. I am unable to reach the server. I have verified the both host and port number both are same. still dint connecting to it.Apart from it i have done one thing. i have configured the server in my local machine and trying to connecting to it via IP and port number. My local machine server will connect to external server through some configuration.(the external server IP and port number are different). Any idea which api do i need to use and connect to make it work.